# How do I select specific rows in a server side jQuery data table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using jQuery Data Tables server side example in php to grab records in a table and then display them as illustrated in this example:

http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/server_side.html

My question is: how do I grab only specific records based on a WHERE clause in my sql?

Note that the above example gets all the records in the specified table, allowing us to choose the columns...how do we do the same but selecting only certain rows that fit a certain criteria...i.e. in the example show only Firefox browsers by default when the data table loads. The following is the code from the php script that is called via jquery to populate the data table...I am actually trying to modify this script to get only specific rows, i.e. rows WHERE browser like 'Firefox%' ...

```
 * Filtering
 * NOTE this does not match the built-in DataTables filtering which does it
 * word by word on any field. It's possible to do here, but concerned about efficiency
 * on very large tables, and MySQL's regex functionality is very limited
 */
$sWhere = "";
if ( $_GET['sSearch'] != "" )
{
    $sWhere = "WHERE (";
    for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
    {
        $sWhere .= $aColumns[$i]." LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET['sSearch'] )."%' OR ";
    }
    $sWhere = substr_replace( $sWhere, "", -3 );
    $sWhere .= ')';
}

/* Individual column filtering */
for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
{
    if ( $_GET['bSearchable_'.$i] == "true" && $_GET['sSearch_'.$i] != '' )
    {
        if ( $sWhere == "" )
        {
            $sWhere = "WHERE ";
        }
        else
        {
            $sWhere .= " AND ";
        }
        $sWhere .= $aColumns[$i]." LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['sSearch_'.$i])."%' ";
    }
}


/*
 * SQL queries
 * Get data to display
 */
$sQuery = "
    SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS ".str_replace(" , ", " ", implode(", ", $aColumns))."
    FROM   $sTable
    $sWhere
    $sOrder
    $sLimit
";
$rResult = mysql_query( $sQuery, $gaSql['link'] ) or die(mysql_error());

/* Data set length after filtering */
$sQuery = "
    SELECT FOUND_ROWS()
";
$rResultFilterTotal = mysql_query( $sQuery, $gaSql['link'] ) or die(mysql_error());
$aResultFilterTotal = mysql_fetch_array($rResultFilterTotal);
$iFilteredTotal = $aResultFilterTotal[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you follow the CRUD example in php, the $_GET keys match option setting keys of datatables such as "sSearch" for your where, 'iDisplayStart' and 'iDisplayLength' for limit etc

Comment: I have tried modifying the $sWhere variable with conditions for the where clause...in some cases I am successful and in others I get the json formatting error...so I am torn between addressing this issue via the jquery code and the callbacks versus the actual php script that pulls the data and searches it (hence the modification of the $sWhere variable in the appropriate places)...

Answer (score 0):

I work with .NET and am not too familiar with php so I can't tailor this exactly to your needs, but I'll show you how to get close to the point where you can hopefully work the rest out yourself.

The [fnServerData](http://datatables.net/ref#fnServerData) event will allow you to post your own params for the search - or to be more specific, the aoData. With the aoData.push() method, you can specific the name of your parameter and the value of it. In this example, I'm going to send the selected date to my query, and I'll call that variable "date".

```
"fnServerData": function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
                /* Add some extra data to the sender */
                aoData.push({ "name": "date", "value": $('#datepicker').val() });
                $.getJSON(sSource, aoData, function (json) {
                    /* Do whatever additional processing you want on the callback, then tell DataTables */
                    fnCallback(json);
                });
```

DataTables will then send a POST to a URL with a bunch of params that such as server_processing.php?sEcho=1&iColumns=21&sColumns=&iDisplayStart=0&iDisplayLength=50 with &date=02%2F27%2F2012 at the end (today's date URL encoded).

From your php page, you should be able to pull that param with the $_GET['date'] function I believe, along with the other keys it sends by default. You will need to return your query results as a JSON object though, as you can see at the bottom of the page you linked.

Comment: okay, can you apply this to the following:

http://live.datatables.net/#javascript,html,live

Suppose, we want to load the datatable with ONLY firefox browsers by default...could you check the link above and post the code please...(am completely new to this)

Comment: Unfortunately, [this](http://live.datatables.net/ogalit/2/edit) is the closest I can get which isn't much, since this won't let you add php code in there. I don't mean to sound condescending, but are you familiar with how to create a JSON object and query a database?

Comment: barely my friend...two days ago I decided to learn jquery and data tables :(

Comment: That will be an issue for what you need then. SQL queries shouldn't take too long to learn, and I'm sure you can find a lot of help here on how to create JSON objects in PHP, but that's far outside the scope of this question.

Comment: see the serverside example (I posted) runs a php script that controls all the parameters for the data to be grabbed...my sql is pretty refined, but the php script seems to be geared towards grabbing all the rows within a table...

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean when you say grabbing all the rows within a table. You have a WHERE clause in there that will grab only the rows that contain the search variable.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by modifying my sql in the serverside php script that grabs the data simply by modifying the $sWhere variable accordingly.  In this scenario I am passing a GET variable $userid from my jquery script:

```
          $userid = $_GET['userid'];
    /* 
 * Filtering
 * NOTE this does not match the built-in DataTables filtering which does it
 * word by word on any field. It's possible to do here, but concerned about efficiency
 * on very large tables, and MySQL's regex functionality is very limited
 */

$sWhere = "WHERE userid=$userid";
if ( isset($_GET['sSearch']) && $_GET['sSearch'] != "" )
{
    $sWhere = "WHERE userid=$userid and (";
    for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
    {
        $sWhere .= $aColumns[$i]." LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET['sSearch'] )."%' OR ";
    }
    $sWhere = substr_replace( $sWhere, "", -3 );
    $sWhere .= ')';
}
```